# What does "doesn't half go on" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

What does "Doesn't half go on" mean? 
The full context:

*"..said Dad impatiently. 'You don't go to Llanpistyll to go shopping.' 
'Obviously not,' said Mum. She sighed. 'I like shopping.' 
'So do I,' I said. Dad sighed too. Even more impatiently. 'Boys don't like shopping,' he said. 'I worry  about you sometimes, Tim.'
I worry about my dad sometimes too. **He 
doesn't half go on**. And on and on. "*

(From "Buried Alive", a children book)

Comment: Here, *doesn't half* and *go on* are the phrases, not *half go on*.

Answer (score 2):

When you "go on" about something, it means that you talk about something at length and keep talking about it.  One of the reasons people "go on" sometimes is that they're having a bit of a fit about it.  With that in mind and given the context, I'd take it to mean that his dad doesn't "go on" in any half measures but instead goes the distance.  It's meant to say that when his dad goes on about something, he really goes on.  He can't let it go.  He keeps going on. And on and on.

Comment: I suspect you are partly correct. the full phrase is **doesn't half go on**  ... hard to find a reference of authority, though it is found in many gooble books.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is.  I know it's "doesn't half go on."  I paraphrased that as "doesn't go on in any half measures."  I surmised that meaning, which became quite clear, by actually opening the book in Google Books and reading the entire section for context.

Answer (score 1):

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/half) gives the following as the second adverb definition and examples:

> *informal* To an extreme degree; very much so.
>
> *She didn't half flare up!*
>
> *Anyway, it didn't half give me backache, pulling it.*

It means, My father really likes to belabor a point.  And then some.